# Apache Virtual Hosts Basic Config

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm trying to convert my personal hosted sites from nginx to apache to support some more advanced stuff I want to host.

I host multiple sites on this single machine using multiple server directives in nginx which works perfectly. I have a single website being served on port 80 as well as several other on port 443 with proper ssl certs and all that.

I've tried finding basic tutorials for apache, but they all appear to be very outdated or using custom distro-specific configs that don't apply, I'm hosting on Arch.

My problem boils down to this:

I know that the main conf file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf configures the listening ports, serverroot, documentroot and directory directives for hosting a single site.

And including /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf lets me add sites I want like:

```
<VirtualHost myhttpsite.com:80>
    ServerName myhttpsite.com
    ServerAlias *.myhttpsite.com
    DocumentRoot /www/myhttpsite.com
    <Directory /www/myhttpsite.com>
        Options ....
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost mysecuresite.dev:443>
    ServerName mysecuresite.dev
    ServerAlias *.mysecuresite.dev
    DocumentRoot /www/mysecuresite.dev
    <Directory /www/mysecuresite.dev>
        Options ....
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Those virtual hosts will all point to subdirectories located at /www/SITENAME

My primary question is, with the virtual hosts included and configured correctly, what if any goes in the primary conf file for the DocumentRoot and Directory directives?

Additionally, is the duplication of DocumentRoot and Directory in the virtual hosts expected? In what case would the values of each of those not be the same?

And finally the question that prompted all of this, why am I getting `AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /www/myhttpsite.com/` in my apache error logs when attempting to access myhttpsite.com?

With nginx everything was working, so DNS is configured correctly. I turned off nginx, started apache and it seems that the config is preventing access (I have chowned the /www/SITES directories to be -R USER:http with rx access for all)